# Replace rectangle shape image fill with another rectangle shape's image fill

Tags: excel, vba

I have a rectangle shape with an image fill on my main sheet (Sheet1) and I have multiple rectangle shape's (with image fills) on my second sheet (Sheet2).

I'm trying to make the the rectangle on sheet1 change based on the cell on sheet2 that contains the other rectangle.

The cell it will point to has a variable assigned to it (art_locator).

```
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes("cardart1").Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .UserPicture = art_locator
        .TextureTile = msoFalse
    End With
```

I think the issue is with .UserPicture as I'm guessing this only allows for a file path? What can I replace it with so I can type in the variable name (art_locator) which should then point it to a cell on sheet2 that has the rectangle image fill I want?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you share more of your code? i.e. is `art_locator` a `Range`?

Comment: Yep, art_locator is a range. It's dependent on user selection on a drop down box and what cell their selection matches to in another sheet. So for example, depending on their selection, art_locator would return C3 which contains a rectangle with an image fill which is what I'm trying to replace cardart1 (on sheet1) with

Comment: Similar to your last question, you'll have to loop through the shapes on sheet2 to find the one that's in C3. Have to think about how to then accomplish what you want.

Comment: What's the reason for looping when the code is already set up to know the cell that contains the image already? The bit I'm trying to work out now is how to take the fill from one cell and apply it to the other - thanks for your help by the way! definitely appreciate it

Comment: Because you can't identify a shape from the cell alone in a direct way, as far as I know. Shapes exist apart from the cells.

Comment: Ah that would explain why I haven't been able to find anything online where you can identify the shape/image from a cell. 

So how would the logic work here? The loop would look for a shape's location and if the location matches the variable cell (art_locator) then it gets the name of the shape and assigns it to a variable which can then be put on to cardart1's shape fill?

Comment: Something more or less like that, I assume, but will need to code it out myself to verify. Can you share your code that determines `art_locator`?

Comment: So I've been working on an alternative. The file path of the image is stored as a variable. I've made it so this fills the cell with the path of the file and the image on top (so the path is hidden visually but the cell has the path as the value).

Now I'm trying to figure out how to tell the sheet1 dynamic image to point to the value of the cell (the file path) to get its image

        .UserPicture (art_locator)

this doesn't seem to work... the variable "art_locator" returns C3 for example but I get the error "Method of 'user picture' of object 'FillFormat' failed"

Comment: Are there multiple shapes on the sheet that have picture fills?

Comment: Once you have located the correct shape containing the image, you can pick up the formatting and apply it to another shape. Shp2.PickUp .Shp1.Apply

Comment: Ah that's a good point, it's probably looking on sheet1, I've got sheet2 set as ws2, but what's the formatting of .userpicture? I've tried .UserPicture ws2.(art_locator) and (ws2.art_locator)

Comment: @Jenn that's the answer, nice. Did not know of `PickUp` and `Apply`. Add it and I'll upvote.

Comment: Jenn, would your method only be used if I looped through to find the shape name? If I ended up doing this the other way, as described above with the file path, would your suggestion of pickup/apply not apply?

Comment: @Sam you need the *value* of that cell, not the address right?

Comment: Correct, I've tried adding .Value to the end of the variable within the .UserPicture part but didn't seem to work either

Comment: `.UserPicture ws2.Range(art_locator).Value`?

Comment: @Sam Yes, you would have to first have the shape identified. Glad you got it what you needed.